# Difference between DynamoDB Conditional Writes and Transaction Writes

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

I'm currently doing a transaction across two tables. I update the value of 1 table based on whether the Flag is T/F in the 2nd table and also update the 2nd table to Flip the value From F to T.

This operation is super expensive for me. Is there a possibility I could replicate the same using Conditional Writes?

Comment: Conditional expressions can't span tables.

Comment: Can you leverage some kind of cache based distributed lock instead of DynamoDB transactions?

Comment: @YeshodhanKulkarni : I could but that was increase the dependencies and open more avenues for failure.